# How to change rest url json extension to base url in Rails4

Tags: json, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

By default rails sets up the rest routes as:
Get /users.json
/users renders scaffolded views.

I am developing an api application and I dont need scaffolded views.

How can get rid of the views part of an existing application.

And how can I switch the json endpoints to base urls like /users

Any recommendation of an existing gem will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think rails setup a default for routes?  Use you're using it purely as an API.. in which case it might..

You need to setup a folder corresponding to the controller/model which rails looks in.   Then it depends on file extension from there.

I can setup `.html` or `.js`. or `.json`  .. and the route works accordingly..

OR

Can you not just add `respond_to` either `.js` or `.html` to the controller?

For the scaffold views, you can just delete them from the folder.

Comment: I would rather the configuration be universal, and be set in the initializer there are going to be many endpoints and i would hate to repeat